# get drawables names(with chinese characters) in android

Tags: android

I´m currently developing a game for Android and I need to get the names(just the names) of the pictures I store in the drawable folder.
I happen to try this code:

```
Class resources = R.drawable.class;
Field[] fields = resources.getFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
field.getName();

}
```

But somehow, it can´t identify files chinese characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a limitation in the Android build system.  It only understands a small set of characters in those folders-  you can't even use capital english letters.  There's no workaround to it, they just didn't make the build system international friendly.

Comment: thanks for the info, although it won´t help me, it´s good to know.

Comment: @FabioPhillipRochaMarques There may be a possible work around to this if you store them as unicode values and then decode them in the program, though that would make your image titles in the folder look odd. Like *'\xe9\xe1\xed\xf3\xfa.png'*. You'd obviously need to work around the backslashes though.